# Invalid location of tag <div> in JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

I insert some code HTML in my jsp page: `acceuil.jsp`, but I'm getting an error in my tag `<div class="ca-content">`.  It shows me that it's an invalid location.  (the `ca-content` is referring to a class in my stylesheet).

I tried to disable the HTML validator but I'm still having the same error.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/acceuil.css" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="ca-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">A</span>

                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
                </div>
   
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<div>` isn't valid inside an `<a>`.

In [HTML 4.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A) that `<a>` elements may only contain [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline) and `<div>` is a [block element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#block), so it may not appear inside an `<a>`.

So, instead:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">A</span>

    <div class="ca-content">
        <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
    </div>

</a>
```

Use:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">A</span>
</a>
<div class="ca-content">
    <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
    <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
</div>
```

Or something else that represents what you need, but always with `<div>` outside `<a>`

Take a look at ["`The a element`"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) in HTML 5 specification, may help you.